# How to create initial value estimation using expectation-maximization algorithm in SPSS?

Tags: spss, expectation-maximization

I would like to use EM algorithm to create initial values in spss.

I have used missing value analysis in spss and also selected EM and also I chose 500 times as the maximum number of iterations but after running the spss I just get one set of data! But I also got the EM means and covariance.

My question is how I can use these numbers to create initial values to be able to run imputation model?

Answer (score 0):

The MVA procedure in Statistics produces a single imputed value for each missing case.  If you want to use multiple imputation, you need to use the MULTIPLE IMPUTATION procedure.

Comment: THanks JKP, before multiple imputation in spss we should generate random seeds I would like to use EM algorithm to produce random seed in this way multiple imputation uses data which follow EM distribution instead of random seeds.

Comment: I do 't think there is a way to do that.